# Does this theorem holds out for spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, volume

The theorem:

> Let $F$ and $C$ be two finite geometric figures (those defined by two continuous functions in a given region $D$), where $F$ belongs to an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space and $C$ is the result of applying a transformation $T$ to $F$ that introduces curvature on its surface, placing it in a non-Euclidean space of $n+1$ dimensions. If the hypersurfaces of $F$ and $C$ viewed from an $n+1$ dimensional space are identical but the figures are not identical as a whole, then the magnitude of the hypervolume of $C$ is greater than that of $F$.

When I say "$n$-dimensional Euclidean space" I refer to one space in which you can make an $n$-dimensional triangle that sums up to 180º degrees. For example, if you pick 3 galaxies and draw a huge beam of light between the three you get one that holds that property.

Is this theorem correct for our 4-dimensional spacetime? How do you provide a proof? Is this question only proper for the Math StackExchange?

Comment: Regardless of where to ask it, I think the question needs a lot more clarity. What do you mean by "defined by a continuous function", and why does that guarantee that the figure is bounded (which is what I assume you mean by finite)? Can the transformation $T$ be literally anything? What do you mean by the hypersurfaces of the figures, and what does it mean to view them from a space?

Comment: Isn't this basically the map making problem? How do we project a square map on a round globe? The trivial answer is that it's not possible. The more complex answer is that it can be done with multiple maps and giving up some things (area conservation, distance conservation, length conservation). In general the question of the existence of flat embeddings seems to be one of the more complicated problems of Riemannian geometry if I remember correctly. Partial answers are known and they are unpleasant for physicists (4d spacetime needs 10 flat embedding dimensions, or so).